# What's wrong with this code(JavaScript, buttons, HTML)?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Question 2</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick="myFunction()">Alphabetical order</button>
    <button onClick="countFunction">Count</button>

    <p id="i"></p>
    <p id="ii"></p>

    <script>
        var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Keyboard"];
        document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = products;

        function myFunction() {
            products.sort();
            document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = products;
        }

        function countFunction() {
            document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = products.length;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think it's just a spelling or formatting error. If you can change the code as little as possible while still fixing it I would appreciate it a lot. If you need any more details please just ask. I would be happy to provide as much information as I can to help you help me.

This is for my son - he loves traffic lights!

Comment: You've missed brackets on the second button's function in the onClick attribute, as far as i'm aware that's the only bug I can see. Although i'm not sure why you have the second p tag, unless you wanted to make that the count value, in which case you need to change the element id in countFunction to "ii"

Comment: Thank you so much. In an earlier version I had more stuff in p2 but that's secret...

Comment: Ah right, in that case i'll modify my answer. Also if I helped you at all then please feel free to select my answer as the correct one/vote it up, would really appreciate it, thanks :)

Comment: You may want to add what part is not working - see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/BrechtDeMan/c0yah00s/) for a JSFiddle demonstrating your page. See my answer for the working version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify these lines:

```
<button onClick="myFunction();">Alphabetical order</button>

<button onClick="countFunction();">Count</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Set `type` of buttons to `button`. Default `type` is `submit` so on
  clicking your function doesn't execute and page is submitted.
- `onClick` should be `onclick`.
- You are missing `()` after    `countFunction` so add `()` at end of
  `countFunction`

  ```
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Alphabetical order</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="countFunction()">Count</button>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the brackets inside the second `onclick` attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Question 2</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
</head>



<body>


<button onClick="myFunction()">Alphabetical order</button>

<button onClick="countFunction()">Count</button>


<p id="i"></p>

<p id="ii"></p>


<script>


var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Keyboard"];

document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = products;


function myFunction() {

    products.sort();

    document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = products;
}



function countFunction() {
    document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = products.length;

}



</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Now if you use the code, the first button will sort the array into alphabetical order and the second one will display the number of values, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify this:
countFunction changed to countFunction()

Answer (score 0):

See here for a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/BrechtDeMan/hzg4zefb/

#### 1. Add brackets to the function call in the `onclick=` bit

I.e. `<button onClick="countFunction()">Count</button>` instead of `<button onClick="countFunction">Count</button>`.

#### 2. Get the right HTML element

Your code now has

```
document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = products.length;
```

meaning the array is then replaced with the number '4'.

Presumably you want

```
document.getElementById("ii").innerHTML = products.length;
```

so that the output is

```
Printer,Tablet,Router,Keyboard

4
```

#### 3. Best practices

This will change your code as little as possible, like you asked.

However, there are other improvements that might improve the style of your code. 
Technically the code works like this (barring compatibility issues I'm not aware of - it works for me).